# Debian Wheezy - Installing cross-toolchains

Tags: debian, arm, cross-compilation

I would like to compile a kernel on Arm platform using this line:

```
 make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- uImage
```

But I need a package I can't find:

```
/bin/sh: 1: arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld: not found
```

As this [page](http://linux-sunxi.org/Toolchain), I need to install **g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf** but I can't find it, just find this: [people.debian.org/~wookey/tools/debian](https://people.debian.org/~wookey/tools/debian/) or [Emdebian](https://wiki.debian.org/CrossToolchains#For_Wheezy) repo (not disponible for wheezy).

So my question: How can I install the unstable package from wookey ?

Comment: I don't want to discourage you from asking here - this seems like a reasonable question, and god knows we don't get that many of them - but you might get a quicker answer on the debian arm mailing list or even irc. Even email wookey directly might be an answer, though in some cultures that is frowned upon.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your response. I will try to ask at ARM's specialists !

Comment: I think I must compile the kernel with a x64 computer. I will try in my i5 Kubuntu.